# How to merge text of alphabetic lines with the numeric lines in shell?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting, regular-expression, merge

I Have a file that has text like this:

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD

1234
5678
9012
3456

EEEE 

7890
```

etc...

And i want to match up the Alphabetic lines with the Numeric lines so they are like this:

```
AAAA 1234 
BBBB 5678
CCCC 9012
DDDD 3456

EEEE 7890
```

Does anyone know of a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: You mention `emacs`.. Are you looking for an `elisp` solution, or how to run a shell-script from within emacs?

Comment: In Vim: [Merge multiple lines (two blocks)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10760326/55075) at SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `perl`:

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

## Check arguments.
die qq[Usage: perl $0 <input-file>\n] unless @ARGV == 1;

my (@alpha, @digit);

while ( <> ) {
        ## Omit blank lines.
        next if m/\A\s*\Z/;

        ## Remove leading and trailing spaces.
        s/\A\s*//;
        s/\s*\Z//;

        ## Save alphanumeric fields and fields with
        ## only digits to different arrays.
        if ( m/\A[[:alpha:]]+\Z/ ) {
                push @alpha, $_;
        }
        elsif ( m/\A[[:digit:]]+\Z/ ) {
                push @digit, $_;
        }
}

## Get same positions from both arrays and print them
## in the same line.
for my $i ( 0 .. $#alpha ) {
        printf qq[%s %s\n], $alpha[ $i ], $digit[ $i ];
}
```

Content of `infile`:

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD

1234
5678
9012
3456

EEEE 

7890
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl infile
```

And result:

```
AAAA 1234
BBBB 5678
CCCC 9012
DDDD 3456
EEEE 7890
```

Comment: Interesting... Your two regex substitution lines which *Remove leading and trailing spaces* run about 1.6 times faster than a single line which uses backreferencing and non-greedy: `s/\A\s*(.*?)\s*\Z/\1/`.

Answer (score 4):

```
<input sed -nr '/^[A-Z]{4}$/,/^$/w out1
                /^[0-9]{4}$/,/^$/w out2'
paste -d' ' out1 out2 |sed 's/^ $//'
```

or, in a single step, without temp files

```
paste -d' ' <(sed -nr '/^[A-Z]{4}$/,/^$/p' input) \
            <(sed -nr '/^[0-9]{4}$/,/^$/p' input) | sed 's/^ $//'
```

The last `sed` step removes the delimiter on the blank lines, which is introduced by `paste`...

Answer (score 4):

In `awk`, preserving empty lines, assuming the file is well formatted, but logic could be added to check the file:

```
awk -v RS="" '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i]=$i
  getline
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print a[i] " " $i
  print ""}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

With emacs use [rectangle operations](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html) to cut the text lines and paste them before the numerical lines.

Comment: Thanks, but not really suitable for 15000+ lines! + 1 for a working idea and you need the rep :)

Answer (score 2):

If the entries are in order,

1. Split the input into alphabetic entries and numeric entries, using `grep`:

   - `grep "[[:alpha:]]\+" < file > alpha`
   - `grep "[[:digit:]]\+" < file > digit`
2. Join the two resulting files, `alpha` and `digit`, using `paste`:

   - `paste alpha digit` (you can add `-d " "` so it uses a space instead of a tab)

Comment: Without temp files: `paste <(grep "[[:alpha:]]\+" file) <(grep "[[:digit:]]\+" file)` or with a single process substitution: `grep "[[:alpha:]]\+" file | paste - <(grep "[[:digit:]]\+" file)`.

Answer (score 1):

Too bad awk doesn't have nice push/pop/unshift/shift functions. Here's a short Perl snippet

```
perl -M5.010 -lne '
  given ($_) {
    when (/^[[:alpha:]]+$/) {push @alpha, $_}
    when (/^\d+$/) {say shift(@alpha), " ", $_}
    default {say}
  }
'
```

Comment: When I run it, it outputs an extra (leading) blank line per group.

Comment: Due to the `default` clause, blank lines are immediately printed, so the blank before "1234" will show before the "AAAA" line.

Answer (score 0):

Give file with text, try using `pr` and process substitutions syntax as below:

```
$ pr -mt <(grep -i "^[a-z]" file.txt) <(grep -i "^[0-9]" file.txt)
AAAA                    1234
BBBB                    5678
CCCC                    9012
DDDD                    3456
EEEE                    7890
```

You can adjust width by `-w9` or remove spaces by `sed "s/ //g"`.